Comedy I saw on TV yesterday but can't remember
Yesteday, I saw a commercial of an American TV show.
I think it's a show, it might be a movie, but I'm pretty sure it's a show. It looks like a romantic comedy type of show, but since the romantic partner appeared to not be the main character I'm not sure.
The commercial said it was about this African American male (with glasses, slender, medium build) finally finding love with the one of the main character of the show which is a blonde female.
They show some funny scenes (like when he tries to tell her his name [which starts with sound "na"] and she struggles to pronounce it so she calls him Ariana Grande)
The title is something like "The ____  ______". Basically the title is short (composed of a noun and an adjective which I believe began with a "c").  The commercial ends with two supposed main characters (a the blonde girl and an older white haired man) posing in front of a blue background.
I thought it was on ABC but I looked and I didn't see it so it's probably not. I believe it is a new show because I've never heard of it before.

You might want to merge your accounts following the guidance presented here. This will enable you to take control of all your previosu content. For now, I'll delete the previous version of the question for you, though.

You might still want to provide a more descriptive question title.

The show is likely The Good Place.
The show has

An African American who is the soul mate of the lead blonde girl (Kristen Bell)
Features "a the blonde girl and an older white haired man" (Ted Danson) with a mostly blue background






The video link doesn't appear to work any more.
